# Entity Framework build predicate (Expression<Func<T, bool>>) with Contains without link to DbSet

Tags: c#, entity-framework, expression, expression-trees

With [universal PredicateBuilder](https://petemontgomery.wordpress.com/2011/02/10/a-universal-predicatebuilder/) it is possible to build predicates without link to DbSet. For examle I have classes

```cs
public class Сountry
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public bool IsSchengen { get; set; }
}

public class Institute
{ 
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int CountryId { get; set; }
    public bool IsNational { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

Build predicate with PredicateBuilder:

```cs
public static Expression<Func<Institute, bool>> BuilPredicate(bool isNational)
{
    var predicate = new PredicateBuilder<Institute>()
           .And(ao => ao.IsNational == isNational);
    
    return predicate.Build();
}
```

Now I need to filter Institutes by Сountries:

```cs
public static Expression<Func<Institute, bool>> BuilPredicate(
    bool isNational, 
    bool countryIsSchengen, 
    DbContext db) // <== don't want to pass link to DbContext 
{
    var predicate = new PredicateBuilder<Institute>()
           .And(ii => ii.IsNational == isNational);
    

    // filter by countries
    // question: how to make the same without DbContext

    var countyIds = db.Set<Сountry>()
        .Where(cc => cc.IsSchengen == countryIsSchengen)
        .Select(cc => cc.Id);
    
    predicate.And(ii => countyIds.Contains(ii.CountryId));
        

    return predicate.Build();
}
```

Is it possible to create such predicate without link to DbContext?
And without navigation Country property:

```cs
public class Institute
{ 
    public int Id { get; set; }

    // without this 
    // public Country Country { get; set; }

    public int CountryId { get; set; }
    public bool IsNational { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: To expand a predicate use `predicate = predicate.And(...)`. BTW, if you use the predicate builder as-is, there is no `new PredicateBuilder()` and `Build` is not one of its methods. You can return `predicate` right away.

Comment: @GertArnold thank you for the comment. I really use custom PredicateBuilder with Build() method, I forgot to mention this. I think this fact does not affect the question.

Comment: But what is it for? It's not clear why it's there (seems not necessary) and how it affects the predicate you create. For the rest, use a navigation property Institute.Country to build the `IsSchengen` predicate.